# List files recursively, in alphabetical order and without lines that show exclusively folder names

Tags: files, find, tree

How to list files recursively, in alphabetical order and without lines that show exclusively folder names?

For example, I can get the following output with `tree --dirsfirst -fihan * -o filelist`:

```
00.-ScriptHookV [1.0.1737.0]
[128K]  00.-ScriptHookV [1.0.1737.0]/dinput8.dll*
[1.2M]  00.-ScriptHookV [1.0.1737.0]/ScriptHookV.dll*
01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]
[ 891]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/LICENSE.txt*
[1.8K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/README.txt*
[1018K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.dll*
[7.5K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.pdb*
[ 92K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.xml*
[ 34K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet.asi*
02.-Heap Limit Adjuster [1.0.0]
[ 98K]  02.-Heap Limit Adjuster [1.0.0]/GTAV.HeapAdjuster.asi*
03.-OpenIV [3.1]
[132K]  03.-OpenIV [3.1]/OpenIV.asi*
04.-Enhanced Native Trainer [1.41 Update 1]
[ 15M]  04.-Enhanced Native Trainer [1.41 Update 1]/EnhancedNativeTrainer.asi*
[8.4K]  04.-Enhanced Native Trainer [1.41 Update 1]/ent-config.xml*
```

But I need this kind of output (not necessarily with filesizes):

```
[128K]  00.-ScriptHookV [1.0.1737.0]/dinput8.dll
[1.2M]  00.-ScriptHookV [1.0.1737.0]/ScriptHookV.dll
[ 891]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/LICENSE.txt
[1.8K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/README.txt
[1018K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.dll
[7.5K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.pdb
[ 92K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet2.xml
[ 34K]  01.-ScriptHookVDotNet [2.10.10]/ScriptHookVDotNet.asi
[ 98K]  02.-Heap Limit Adjuster [1.0.0]/GTAV.HeapAdjuster.asi
[132K]  03.-OpenIV [3.1]/OpenIV.asi
[ 15M]  04.-Enhanced Native Trainer [1.41 Update 1]/EnhancedNativeTrainer.asi
[8.4K]  04.-Enhanced Native Trainer [1.41 Update 1]/ent-config.xml
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty portable:

```
find . -type f | sort
```

On the off chance that your input data contains files with new lines in their name, I believe this should handle them better (thanks to Kusalananda for pointing out this possible scenario):

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: A file named `$'3\n2\n1'` would end up listed weirdly since `sort` sorts line, not filenames.

Comment: That’s a fair point, but assumes facts not in evidence. Also the input looks an awful lot like Windows files to me – and Windows does not support new lines in file names, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: And assuming these are Windows files is not doing the same thing?

Comment: The names of the files are the evidence for my assumption.

Comment: Thanks, I'll always use the 2nd option just in case, this worked great, and yes, these are windows files, GTA V mods organized by install order

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
print -C1 **/*(.DN)
```

With the `zsh` shell this would print the result of expanding the given globbing pattern as a single column (this is what `print -C1` does).  The pattern `**/*(.DN)` expands to the pathnames of all regular files (not directories etc.; this is what the glob qualifier `(.)` does) in or beneath the current directory.  These will, by default, be orderer in lexicographical order. The `(DN)` glob qualifier has the same effect as setting `dotglob` and `nullglob`, respectively, in the `bash` shell (i.e. it makes the pattern match hidden names and also makes it expand to nothing at all if it doesn't match anything).

Instead of `(.)` to only list regular files, one could instead use `(^/)` to list non-directories.

In `bash`, you can do something similar with

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob
for pathname in **/*; do
    [[ ! -d $pathname ]] && printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
done
```

which prints the lexicographically sorted pathnames of all non-directories (including hidden files) recursively.

Comment: POSIX-ly, and also cleaner design: `! [ -d "$pathname" ] && ...`, still not really relevant since you rely on `shopt` in there... but I thought of it merely as for new readers to learn clean designs. | +1

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Yeah, when you pull in `globstar` and the others in a `bash` script, you might as well use other `bash` features without worrying too much about POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to list all the files in all the sub-directories from your current directory and sort on filename use the find command.

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the directory name included with the file name, but not lines which are *solely* the directory name.

Comment: Exactly, directory name included but without lines which are solely the directory name